# My tab still asks me to sign in to a wifi network which I have been using perfectly well till last months

Tags: wi-fi, password

**These are the details:**

1. I'm using Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.5 (805)
2. I can use other wifi networks since the issue started, but I can't use the one at home.
3. I can go online but it disconnects automatically after a few seconds.
   Page directs me directly to google and there isn't any sign in prompt there
4. Nobody else is having the same problem that I have

**These are the remedies that I've tried:**

1. Obvious reset of router/phone, I've even restored the router to default and reconfigured it again but still didn't work
2. Changed wifi setting from dhcp to static but still didn't work.
3. Cleared cache data but still didn't work.
4. For your information, my data plan is unlimited.

I hope anyone can suggest something that I haven't tried before, thank you.

[image]